# How to properly use JSON to exchange data between separate pages

Tags: html, json

I have the following html code which is just an item name from a view cart page. I want to be able to transfer this data (amongst others once i get the basic idea down) to a separate html page that'll automatically generate a list of multiple items, with multiple prices and output a total price.

```
<div class="product-name-options"> 
            <!--START: itemnamelink--><a id="itemName" href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a><!--END: itemnamelink--> 

<button type="button" onclick="window.location='Quote_ep_78-1.html'" id="vc_ChkButton" class="btn"><i class="icon-basket"></i> Get Quote</button>

</div>
```

I have the following Json code on the cart page.

```
 <script>

       window.onload = 
  function createStudent(){


      // this is how you set it
    var newProduct = new Object();

    newProduct.itemName= document.getElementById('itemName');


    if(localStorage.product)
    {
     product= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('product'));
    }else{
     product=[];
    }
    product.push(newProduct)
    localStorage.setItem('product', JSON.stringify(product));





}


    </script>
```

This is the quote page.

```
  <script>

        window.onload= function jsonStarter(){
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('product');

           /* document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = retrievedObject;*/



       console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

}

    </script>





</head>

<body>


    <div id = ".myDivClass">




    </div>



   </body>
```

I can't seem to get the jSON data appear in the div that i've made furthermore at the moment i get the following.

```
"retrievedObject:  (2) [{…}, {…}]"
```

I get the above console.log which i believe is correct as it reflects the number of items in my cart but i can't get it to print anything else. This is my first ever time using JSON so i'm a bit out of my depth but i'm eager to learn how to do this.

The quote page div after all this looks like this;

```
<div id=".myDivClass">[{"itemName":{"__hj_mutation_summary_node_map_id__":1063}},{"itemName":{"__hj_mutation_summary_node_map_id__":1063}},{"itemName":{"__hj_mutation_summary_node_map_id__":1063}}]</div>
```

Comment: You can put the JSON in the localstorage and retrieve it on the next page.

Comment: The API is https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage that aloows this localy. And connex was faster :-)

Comment: I've changed my code to reflect the changes. I've taken away the loop and now only get one console.log which has i think the correct info. I just need to print that into the html page.

Comment: One thing i've noticed is every time i reload the same tab to test the value of  the retrievedObject goes up by one.